# Insert in batch mode on PostgreSQL 9.6 with Apache Spark 1.6

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Please, there is a configuration or params to do this:

```
dataFrame.write.mode(saveMode).jdbc(url, "tablename", new java.util.Properties())
```

Command is written in Scala, Apache Spark 1.6

That takes a DataFrame and inserts data in PostgreSQL row by row, one by one. We need to do this in batch mode.

Anyone knows if exists any configuration or another way to accomplish that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

According to documentation - [link](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases) - you can use `batchsize` parameter to perform inserts in batches

```
dataFrame
    .write
    .mode(saveMode)
    .option("batchsize", 1000)
    .jdbc(url, "tablename", new java.util.Properties())
```

Now insert will be perfomed in batches of 1000 rows

Comment: Thank you! I used this option suggest by you, but ain't supose that if I query count(*) I will see every few seconds (batch insert) results like 1000, 2000, 3000.. and go on? Because is not like that. I just see from 0 to 50.000 after a few minutes. It seems that is not working this option.

Comment: Based on similar experience with mssql, batchsize do not perform bulk inserts, but performs many inserts per 1 connection